# UIWebView as view for footer in section for tableview. Strange Crash - crash log attached

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uitableview

I have a uitableviewcontroller and im loading a uiwebview as viewForFooterInSection for the tableview

This webview has some html content being loaded.
The app crashes whenever I try to do

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Crash log attached

```
Incident Identifier: DA08DEDA-3566-4A56-938A-57F4BCDF64F1
CrashReporter Key:   ef8a5122f6b5431e4b29802596ec279644f97bd4
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         sample [955]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/A0B6D2C6-AA93-4D24-9C7F-666B8C7F94B4/sample.app/sample
Identifier:      sample
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-24 13:07:10.396 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x35fbc900 WebCore::TileCache::doLayoutTiles() + 24
1   WebCore                         0x3609bed8 -[TileHostLayer renderInContext:] + 28
2   QuartzCore                      0x336cc948 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 220
3   QuartzCore                      0x336cbada -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1086
4   QuartzCore                      0x336cc948 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 220
5   QuartzCore                      0x336cbada -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1086
6   QuartzCore                      0x336cc948 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 220
7   QuartzCore                      0x336cbada -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1086
8   QuartzCore                      0x336cc948 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 220
9   QuartzCore                      0x336cbada -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1086
10  QuartzCore                      0x336cc948 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 220
11  QuartzCore                      0x336cbada -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1086
12  UIKit                           0x35b6b2dc -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _imageViewForView:] + 68
13  UIKit                           0x35b6a66a -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupDeleteAnimationForFooterInSection:withTargetRect:forUpdateItem:] + 370
14  UIKit                           0x35a7f91a -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForDeletedHeadersAndFooters] + 1862
15  UIKit                           0x35a78be6 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport initWithTableView:updateItems:oldRowData:newRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] + 398
16  UIKit                           0x35a77dba -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateWithItems:withOldRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] + 966
17  UIKit                           0x35a7746c -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 4744
18  UIKit                           0x35a812f2 -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 22
19  UIKit                           0x35a812ce -[UITableView endUpdates] + 10
20  sample                      0x00007574 -[TableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (TableViewController.m:188)
21  UIKit                           0x3599c514 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 656
22  UIKit                           0x35a000e4 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 124
23  Foundation                      0x307ee6ce __NSFireDelayedPerform + 362
24  CoreFoundation                  0x34e69a40 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
25  CoreFoundation                  0x34e6bec4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
26  CoreFoundation                  0x34e6c83e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
27  CoreFoundation                  0x34dfcebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
28  CoreFoundation                  0x34dfcdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
29  GraphicsServices                0x30de0418 GSEventRunModal + 108
30  GraphicsServices                0x30de04c4 GSEventRun + 56
31  UIKit                           0x35976d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
32  UIKit                           0x35974800 UIApplicationMain + 664
33  sample                      0x000024ac main (main.m:16)
34  sample                      0x00002440 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36906fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36aa5032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36aa603a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x36aa55ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3663558a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36635bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36903c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36903758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34e6a2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34e6c562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34dfcebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34dfcdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35f1a27e _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3663430a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36635bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36903c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36903758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34e6a2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34e6c562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34dfcebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34dfcdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x307937f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x30786382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x307f85c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3663430a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36635bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36905c60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x34e6f8f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3663430a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36635bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x369063ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x366356d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36635bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x3ef7c298      r2: 0x00562ab2      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x001f8c70    r5: 0x00164f80      r6: 0x2fdfd718      r7: 0x2fdfd68c
    r8: 0x2fdfd6e8    r9: 0x001fc0a0     r10: 0x001f8c70     r11: 0x00164f80
    ip: 0x3f05e428    sp: 0x2fdfd5f4      lr: 0x3609bedf      pc: 0x35fbc900
  cpsr: 0x60000030
```

## **UPDATE 1:**

Ive digged deeper into this and it seems to be some bug with apple unless I've missed something obvious

I tried creating a fresh Master Detail iphone app and added a UIWebView property in the  MasterViewController(UITableViewController) and initialized it

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
@synthesize webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 50.0)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

now I have set this webview as the view for footer for the section in the tableview

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return webView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50.0;
}
```

and in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath I have done the following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Now whenever I touch a row I get the same crash and I have no Idea why this is happening.

This is a totally fresh app with default code in it. I have only added the webView as the footer for the tableview.

Comment: how many sections do you have?

Comment: the tableview has one section and 10 rows

Comment: Just ran into the exact same problem. Tried to set a webview as a footer. The problem seems to be coming from the fact that we are reusing the webview. It works fine if you create a new webview every time viewForFooterInSection is called, but that's inefficient. /:

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty puzzling. Would you try removing the begin/endUpdates:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
```

I see that the crash is happening in `endUpdates`, so all the rest that has been executed up to that point has gone flawlessly.

Another thing you might try is reloading the whole table by calling `reloadData` instead of only reloading the sections through `reloadSections`. This is not as optimized, but since you have few rows it should not matter actually (if it works better)...

OLD ANSWER:

It seems that one of the objects in your table view is being deallocated and then accessed again. This is a typical "zombie" issue.

You can get some clues at what is happening by enabling zombie detection in Xcode.

[Here you can find out how to enable zombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode).

If you do, then the error message you get in the console log will offer more information as to which object was deallocated prematurely.

I understand that you are attaching a crash log because the crash happens in the field. In this case, you have two options: either reproducing the issue at your side (and fix it with the help of zombies detection); or inspect carefully your memory management to find out any issue with objects displayed in the table view.

Comment: Along the same lines: It might also be a good idea to check for issues with the XCode Clang Analyzer `Product -> Analyze` (if you have not already done this)

Comment: I have updated my question. unfortunately, enabling zombie detection and analyzing the project did not help

Comment: Please, see my edit. I cannot find an explanation, but I have proposed two kind of workarounds.

Comment: reloadData does work. The problem is with reloadSection I've tried removing beingUpdates and endUpdates, still crashes. And I need reloadSection to work